# NSPredicate with bitmask for filtering NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, photokit

I'm trying to test whether some particular asset collections contain only one media type/subtype using an `NSPredicate`. The: `testForPhotosPredicate` works just fine, however when trying to use the `testForPanoramasPredicate` it fails with the message: `Unable to parse the format string "mediaSubtypes & %i"`

How can I use a bitmask in this predicate for the mediaSubtypes?

```
for (PHFetchResult *newFetch in collectionFetches)
{
    for (PHAssetCollection *sub in newFetch)
    {
        PHFetchResult *assetsInCollection = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:sub options:fetchOptions];

        NSArray *allAssets = [assetsInCollection objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, assetsInCollection.count)]];

        if (allAssets.count > 0)
        {
            [allAssetsArray addObjectsFromArray:allAssets];

            NSPredicate *testForPhotosPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %i",PHAssetMediaTypeImage];

            NSArray *testForAllPhotos = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForPhotosPredicate];

            if (testForAllPhotos.count == allAssets.count)
            {
                NSPredicate *testForPanoramasPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaSubtypes & %i",PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama];

                NSArray *testForAllPanoramas = [testForAllPhotos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForPanoramasPredicate];

                if (testForAllPanoramas.count == testForAllPhotos.count)
                {
                    NSLog(@"all panos");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have solved it with the below code:

```
NSPredicate *testForPanoramasPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i",PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama];

NSArray *testForAllPanoramas = [testForAllPhotos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForPanoramasPredicate];
```

Perhaps even better yet if you don't want to do the initial image predicate:

```
NSPredicate *testForPanoramasPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"(mediaType == %i && (mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i))",
PHAssetMediaTypeImage,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama];
```

Full code to help others out who specifically want to check if an album contains one particular media subtype; useful for displaying a UI badge on an album.

```
PHFetchResult *assetsInCollection = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:sub options:fetchOptions];

if (assetsInCollection.count > 0)
{
    NSArray *allAssets = [assetsInCollection objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, assetsInCollection.count)]];

    NSPredicate *testForPanoramasPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaType == %i && (mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i))",PHAssetMediaTypeImage,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama];

    NSPredicate *testForHDRPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaType == %i && (mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i))",PHAssetMediaTypeImage,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoHDR,PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoHDR];

    NSPredicate *testForVideosPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %i",PHAssetMediaTypeVideo];

    NSPredicate *testForSlomoPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaType == %i && (mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i))",PHAssetMediaTypeVideo,PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate,PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];

    NSPredicate *testForTimelapsePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaType == %i && (mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i))",PHAssetMediaTypeVideo,PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoTimelapse,PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoTimelapse];

    NSPredicate *testForStreamedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaType == %i && (mediaSubtypes & %i) == %i))",PHAssetMediaTypeVideo,PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoStreamed,PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoStreamed];

    NSArray *testForAllPanoramas = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForPanoramasPredicate];
    NSArray *testForAllHDR = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForHDRPredicate];
    NSArray *testForAllVideos = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForVideosPredicate];
    NSArray *testForAllSlomo = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForSlomoPredicate];
    NSArray *testForAllTimelapse = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForTimelapsePredicate];
    NSArray *testForAllStreamed = [allAssets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testForStreamedPredicate];

    NSArray *allPossibilitiesArray = @[testForAllPanoramas,testForAllHDR,testForAllVideos,testForAllSlomo,testForAllTimelapse,testForAllStreamed];

    for (NSArray *sub in allPossibilitiesArray)
    {
        if (sub.count == allAssets.count)
        {
            PHAsset *firstAsset = sub.firstObject;

            [dataSource setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:firstAsset.mediaSubtypes] forKey:@"MediaSubtype"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want `()` around your `(mediaSubtypes & %i)`, `&` has lower precedence than `==` so it's going to end up evaluating `(mediaSubtypes & (%i == %i))`